# CV2 Returning NoneType for Image?

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently trying to compute the arrays of different images. I have the code below which uses `cv2` to read and then hog.compute to calculate it. However the issue that I am getting is that I am getting a `NoneType` being outputted. I know that the absolute file path which is why I used `os.path.abspath(file)`. However, I know that the file is being read as I have printed the file name and it is the file that is in the directory?

The files are located within a folder called `image_dataset` and this has 3 subfolders called bikes, cars and people. I'm pretty sure the first file is being read as well but have no clue why I am getting a `NoneType` returned when I try `hog.compute(im)`? Any clue as to why?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    
def obtain_dataset(folder_name):
    # assuming 128x128 size images and HoGDescriptor length of 34020
    hog_feature_len=34020
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    
    image_dict = {'bikes':1, 'cars':2, 'people':3}
    
    y = []
    X = []
        
    #code for obtaining hog feature for one image file name

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_name):
        
        for file in files:
            
            if file.lower().endswith(('.png')):
            
                location = (os.path.abspath(file))
                im = cv2.imread(location)
                h = hog.compute(im)

    # use this to read all images in the three directories and obtain the set of features X and train labels Y
    # you can assume there are three different classes in the image dataset
    return (X,y) 

train_folder_name='image_dataset'
(X_train, Y_train) = obtain_dataset(train_folder_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, as you have a subdirectory, the [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) method does not return the complete path of the file. Instead, use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join the file names with the path of the directory of the files:

```
location = os.path.join(subdir, file)
```